# Limitations of Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Im just wondering what are the limitations of Hyperledger Fabric in terms of how much data can be stored on each of the peers?

Following this question I'm wondering what are you options in managing large amounts of data on a Hyperledger network i.e. with decentralised networks etc.

I'm struggling to find good resources on this so it would be great if somebody could fill me in or point me to some good resources on the topic!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad. However, I will cut down a few things and try to answer this as concisely as possible.

The amount of data that can be stored is although a direct function of the peer's capacity, however storing large amounts of data on the ledger is itself not recommended in case of any ledger, because scaling is an issue. You can opt for off chain storage like IPFS to store bulky data off-chain and have the proof of the same as a hash on the ledger. Next, you can try segregating data into channels and have peers join the channel on a need basis.

Moreover, have your data properly indexed (in CouchDB) and consider for replication and scalability aspect of the couch DB itself.

I hope I was able to touch the iceberg. For more details, you can reach me offline for further discussions.